# Showing that every field is an integral domain.

Tags: abstract-algebra

The proof I have starts of with $\;xy=0\;$ in a field.

Then $x^{-1}$ exists because it is a field.

Then $x^{-1} xy=x^{-1} 0$.

Therefore $y=0$.

But surely if an integral domain can not have any zero divisors, how can we end the proof by saying $y=0$? Surely then y is a zero divisor and hence the field is not an integral domain?

Comment: What is the definition of zero divisors?

Comment: $R$ is an integral domain iff whenever $xy=0$ but $x\neq0$ it follows that $y=0$. That is what is being shown here. Also your third formula should end with $x^{-1}0=0$. And a zero divisor is one of $x,y$, _both nonzero_ such that $xy=0$. In other words, $0$ is not a zero divisor.

Answer (score 24):

Let $A$ be a field.

A field is a commutative division ring. So every non-zero element of $A$ is invertible.

Let $x,y \in A$ be such that $xy = 0$. Assume that $(x \neq 0 \  and \  y \neq 0)$.

As $x \neq 0$, $x$ is invertible, so $x^{-1}$ exists. Look at:

$$xy = 0 \implies x^{-1}(xy) = x^{-1}0 \implies (x^{-1}x)y = 0 \implies ey = 0 \implies y = 0$$

A contradiction.

Therefore $x = 0 \ or \ y = 0$.

This shows that $A$ is an integral domain.

What's invalid in your argument is the assumption $x^{-1}$ exists. This need not be true unless $x \neq 0$. I guess that you already understood this after reading my proof.

Answer (score 2):

You must say before your line about the assertion of $x^{-1}$ existing that $x \neq 0$, or else $x^{-1}$ may not exist. So if one element is nonzero and their product is 0, the other element must be 0.

Otherwise, it's great!

Answer (score 2):

You are missing the point: start with $xy=0$ and $x\neq 0$, because we are in a field $x^{-1}$ exists ( remember $x\neq 0$) and you then prove as you did that $y=0$.
In summary whenever $xy=0$ either $x=0$ or $y=0$ and a field is an integral domain

Answer (score 1):

Our aim is to prove xy=0 only when either x=0 or y=0.
Let us assume the contradiction, suppose the field F contains zero divisors, then xy=0 for some non zero x and y.
As x is non-zero, and F is a field,  x^{-1} exists and x^{-1}(xy)=0 which leads to y=0, a contradiction to our assumption that y is non-zero.
This contradiction occured as we assume that F contains zero divisors. Hence F does not contain any zero divisors and it will be an integral domain